# How to copy data from Cassandra to csv file

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I need to copy data from `cassandra` to a file for further testing but I am not able to copy, there are around 400000 records in the table.

When I am using the `COPY` command, it stops the `cassandra` process giving the below error :-

```
TSocket read 0 bytes
```

How can I copy these records in CSV file? Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at your Cassandra's ``system.log`` for errors

Comment: @MikhailStepura - I checked system.log but there is no failure present there.How can I increase Key Cache in cassandara which is by default set to 200000 as I have 400000 records in database ?

Comment: Is there any option like date in COPY command using which I can copy data to file ?